# Dependency Injection: ASP vNext. How is this working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, cqrs, asp.net-core

So in my CQRS-based bug-tracking web-API, I am refactoring my code before progressing and implementing unit tests (which, admittedly, should have come first); I have this class and constructor:

```
public class BugCommandHandler : IBugCommandHandler
{
    private BugContext db;

    public BugCommandHandler(BugContext bugContext)
    {
        db = bugContext;
    }

    //Interface implementation
}
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
public class BugsController : Controller
{
    private IBugCommandHandler commandHandler;
    private BugContext db;

    public BugsController(BugContext bugContext, IBugCommandHandler bugCommandHandler)
    {
        db = bugContext;
        commandHandler = bugCommandHandler;
    }
}
```

And, finally, in my Startup class, I have injected the dependency with

```
services.AddSingleton<IBugCommandHandler, BugCommandHandler>();
```

My Unit Tests and manual Integration Tests are all working fine as they were when I was manually calling this without DI. 


How does the `BugCommandHandler` implementation now work as though it has been called with the database context in its constructor (*behind the scenes 'magic'*)? What is its' process to achieve this?

I've checked out (not like *that*) some of the source code in the Github repo, but can't really find where this may be happening. 

I may be overlooking something crucial, or it may just be well-hidden as it is still in pre-release.

Comment: Since `BugContext` is a concrete object rather than an interface that is being passed into the constructor, the DI framework is just calling the default constructor on it for you and passing it in.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for confirming that for me. Maybe it wasn't 100% clear in my phrasing, however, that I'd like to know just _how_ it does that. So I know the limitations on it and why I can/can't do certain things with it.

Comment: To be a bit more precise, at the spot where you registered your concrete implementation, the IoC framework checked out what constructors were available on `BugCommandHandler`, and found a single constructor, taking an argument of type `BugContext`. That is the constructor it will use when an instance of `IBugCommandHandler` is requested.

Comment: A bit unrelated to your question, but since you're applying CQRS, I find it weird that you define many off-by-one interfaces such as `IBugCommandHandler`, instead of one generic `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`. You are missing out a lot of flexibility and maintainability benefits. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you call `AddSingleton`, the type registration is stored in the DI container. The code is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/b189568c612290652dd482e5f6b8a02324d574cf/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interfaces/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L114-L118).
2. When you add the MVC services by calling `AddMvc`, they are added to the same DI container as the type(s) at step 1. The magic happens [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/015edefa96c2eec7a474489a93a533e10ac74c7e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L18-L23). That's how the container is passed up the stack and shared between components.
3. When MVC activates your controller, it will create an instance using the types in the container; that happens [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/df4b92b1c12dcea122a730b618b33a0b39496561/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DefaultControllerActivator.cs#L26-L30). Eventually, [this code](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/702e9a7af37a20e1276521250d68c739778606b2/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interfaces/ActivatorUtilities.cs#L71-L87) is called. It will try to resolve that service and all its dependencies using the registrations in the container.

In your particular case, you also need `BugContext` to be registered.

You might find useful this article that I wrote a while ago about DI in ASP.NET 5. It is a little outdated in terms of code but the principles are the same: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx

Also, if you really want to see what happens, take a look at the other article that I wrote about debugging the framework code in ASP.NET 5. You can step in MVC and see the exact code path:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx . If you want to see all the code in your scenario you will need the sources for [DependencyInjection](http://github.com/aspnet/dependencyinjection) and [MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/mvc).