# How does ASP.NET 5 inject startup's dependencies?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm studying [ASP.NET 5 documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) (It's great and better than the old one.) I understand that ASP.NET 5 includes a simple built-in inversion of control (IoC) container that supports constructor injection by default. As far as I know, configuring services and dependencies are done inside `ConfigureServices()` method.

The `ConfigureServices()` method is called after `StartUp` method.

**So my question is**: *how does ASP.NET 5 internally inject Startup's dependencies?*

I'd like to know that because if I want to inject another dependency, for example `IFooEnviroment` how can I do that?

Comment: Startup's dependencies are injected by the hosting layer (HostingEngine->StartupLoader-> instantiates your startup class with the dependencies)...not sure if you can do anything here...may i ask why you need to inject in Startup's constructor? what is your scenario?

Comment: Thanks @KiranChalla . I'm just curious to know that it's possible or not.

Comment: A little outdated but here's my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550647/dependency-injection-asp-vnext-how-is-this-working/29580182#29580182

Comment: You could register services in `ConfigureServices()` and let them inject in the `Configure()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for this lives in the [Hosting](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting) layer of ASP.NET 5:

- the `Startup` type is [determined](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs#L43)
- the hosting layer [registers the required runtime services](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L62) in the `IServiceCollection`
- An internal [service provider is build](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L100)
- an instance of the Startup class [is created](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs#L35)

You can of course register your own services in `ConfigureServices`. But they won't be available in the constructor as you already figured. There is no way to add your own services to the runtime services. This makes sense because there should be a difference between *runtime* services and *application* services.

You can however inject services registered in the `ConfigureServices()` method in the `Configure()` method.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to add my services to the runtime services?

Comment: Well, you can. But not _before_ `ConfigureServices()`. That's currently the only way to add services to the service provider without having to take over the complete hosting part.